# How to modify "SHA1" in my released keystore app

Tags: google-play, publishing, sha

I made my app using appsgeyser of which was version0.1.

I made the same app with more features on phonegap and updated my version to 0.2.
 Everything goes fine 
BUT 
while uploading my apk to google store under the same app 
it says that my SHA1 is modified and I have to use the same certificate.

what shall I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Play store requires `.apk` to be signed before you can publish it there.

If you've made an app with AppsGeyser and published it to Play then your application is signed by the AppsGeyser private keys (unless you've explicitly signed the `.apk` before publising it or if you've provided your secret keystore to AppsGeyser which is unlikely).

AppsGeyser [wont give you their keystore](http://www.appsgeyser.com/support/can-i-have-the-apps-keystore.php) and you need it to be able to sign new version of your software. Here is the quote from [docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) about this:

> Your private key is required for signing all future versions of your application. If you lose or misplace your key, you will not be able to publish updates to your existing application. You cannot regenerate a previously generated key.

In other words you have 2 options here. Either stick with AppsGeyser and update your app using their services or publish update to your application as a whole new appliation.